# Handling Back Button in Android without implementing InputProcessor

Tags: android, libgdx, input, screen

Please advice/clarifyon below issue in libgdx while handling back button in Screens.

I have already gone through these 2 threads,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223723/in-libgdx-how-do-i-get-input-from-the-back-button

[Is there a way to capture back button twice in same activity libgdx game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/95390/is-there-a-way-to-capture-back-button-twice-in-same-activity-libgdx-game)

As per suggestion in above two threads, I have done something like this in 2 Screen of my Game,

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen{
    //omitted unnecessary code
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        game.setScreen(game.STS);   //Setting 2nd Screen
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)) {
        System.out.println("mms back");
        //if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.BACK))
        Gdx.app.exit();            // Exiting   
    }
}

public class StageScreen implements Screen{
    //omitted unnecessary code
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)) {
        System.out.println("backed to mms in android");
        //if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.BACK))
        game.setScreen(game.MMS);  //going back to Main screen
    }
}
```

Above code works fine, when I press BACK in Stage Screen to call Main Screen, it exits the app immediately, without stopping in my Main screen, which is as per my expectations because I am using Gdx.input.**isKeyPressed**(Keys.BACK) instead of Gdx.input.**isKeyJustPressed**(Keys.BACK).

But my problem is, when I use Gdx.input.**isKeyJustPressed**(Keys.BACK) method in my Screens, it does not (return true) catch BACK key.

I have already set **Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true)** for my Game.

Any idea, why does isKeyJustPressed not responds while isKeyPressed does?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

After experimenting long time, I came to the conclusion that it is not possible to catch **isKeyJustPressed** method without implementing input processor. So I have used **isKeyPressed** method only, without implementing InputProcessor in my Screens.

I have used a boolean flag to get to know that if back button is kept pressed from last screen, it won't exit in first screen untill unless user push the BACK button again.

```
public boolean backpressed=false;  //defined in Game class

public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {
    //omitted unnecessary code
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            game.setScreen(game.STS);   //Setting 2nd Screen
        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)){
            if(!game.backpressed) {
                game.backpressed=true;
            } else if (game.backpressed) {
                game.backpressed=false;
                Gdx.app.exit();
        } 
    }
}

public class StageScreen implements Screen {
    //omitted unnecessary code
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    ...........
    ............
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.BACK)) {
        game.backpressed=true;
        game.setScreen(game.MMS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected boolean backTo(){
    boolean back = false;

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(KEY_BACK) && keyBack == false){
        System.out.println("KeyBack: "+Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK));
        keyBack = true;
        back = false;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(KEY_BACK) == false && keyBack){
        keyBack = false;
        back = true;
    }
    return back;
}

/**
 * @keyBack is a boolean variable that I use to handle the state if it
 * still pressing or not... It logics works like this:
 * If we press the back key it will not work because
 * @back value is set to false. However after the key back stop
 * pressing it will check if the
 * @keyBack is true and it will see Oh that's true because we used
 * to say it has to be true while pressing back key. Then it will set
 * @keyBack false then it will can't call this method again until the key
 * be pressed again.
 *
 * @KEY_BACK is a constant I made with the 4 value... It is the value of back.
 *
 */
```

Here an example how I used this function:

```
private void menuScene(){
   //Omitted unnecessary code
    if(backTo()){

        if(sceneID == MAIN){
            running = false;
            main.setSceneID(main.TRAVEL);
        } else {
            sceneID = MAIN;
            scene.setRunning(false);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case after press back my UI delivery the user to a menu and if the user press back again it will delivery to the MainMenu(Load Game and New Game) passing the constant TRAVEL because the MainMenu has also a map where displays where is the user char in currenty slot.